# Unexpected Apple ID verification?

Tags: iphone, apple-id, authentication

I haven't logged out of any apps, and no apps were running on the iPhone when I picked up the iPhone and pressed the home button to check the battery level.  It had a notification to "verify Apple ID."  I wondered whether somebody was trying to steal my password.  It appeared to be the actual settings app, and I used the double-home to see what applications were running.  Only settings.  But the ID it wanted to verify was a **previous** Apple ID that I changed several months ago.  I didn't do it, but if I did, it would have failed.

What would be the reason for this?

Comment: Do you still have apps installed downloaded with that Apple ID?

Comment: Yes, BUT I did not make a new Apple ID—I just changed the ID (e-mail address).  So it’s the same account.  Besides, no apps were running, so none of them should have suddenly needed authentication. (And most of the installed apps never need authentication.)